# Visual Studio 2015 displays incomplete text, menues and titles

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio doesn't display windows, content, menues etc properly. Text is missing all over the place - as shown on the image. Anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a graphics driver/hardware acceleration issue. Try updating your graphics drivers or turn off hardware graphics acceleration in the Tools -> Options -> General.

[image]